# htaccess - Redirecting all traffic to another domain except existing 301's

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

My htaccess file is filled with 301 redirects like such:

`Redirect 301 /old-page.html https://www.example.com/new-page`

There are about 100 of these redirects. What I would like to do is redirect all traffic going to the old site to go to the new site excluding the existing 301's

So if someone goes to `old-site.com/old-page.html` it will take them to `new-site.com/new-page` and if someone goes to `old-site.com/random-page.html` it will take them to `new-site.com` - just the home page.

Is it possible to do this using mod_rewrite and mod_alias without rewriting the current 301's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep all your 301 rules. Just insert this generic 301 rule **below your existing rule**:

```
# all existing 301 rules go here

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?old-site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://new-site.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however when I add this in, everything redirects to the new site home page and the 301 rules get ignored completely.

Comment: It won't ignore any 301 rules that are **above this rule**. Make sure to clear your browser cache when you test.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `RewriteCond` in front of all your rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)domain\.com$ [NC]
```

If you want all the following rules to be processed as well DO NOT use the L (last) flag in the `RewriteCond` statement.

Source: [Redirect all urls exactly, just change domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816284/redirect-all-urls-exactly-just-change-domain-name)